SÓLO IMPRIME LOS NÚMEROS DE LA ÚLTIMA COLUMNA PYGAMES
Buen día,
Estoy haciendo mi primer juego conocido "2048" en pygame, el juego me funciona correctamente, pero los números cuándo pido que se muestren no lo hacen. Sino sólo los de la última columna.
Si me pudieran ayudar, ya he leído la documentación de pygames, pero no me dicen algo acerca de porque se selecciona sólo la última columna a imprimir los números de las columnas primeras.
Esté es mi código completo, importé constantes que son el tamaño de las casillas y del juego, también los colores que estan en el archivo constantes.
Este es mi código:
https://gist.github.com/Col0rblind/1895d85e6b860720afcd71bcac88bb41/e4fa5467ac4b3063513d6741afe8e5759c7660ac
Este es el fragmento que contiene el cómo estoy mandando a imprimir los números:
def draw_screen():
    screen.fill(constantes.WHITE)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size= 60)
    message_font = pygame.font.Font(None, size = 30)

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            value = board[i][j]
            color = constantes.COLORS.get(value, constantes.COLORS[0])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,
                             rect = (j * constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                                     i * constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                                         constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                                         constantes.CELL_SIZE), width = 0)
        if value != 0:
            text = font.render(str(value), antialias=True, color=constantes.BLACK, bgcolor= None)
            text_rect = text.get_rect(center = (j * constantes.CELL_SIZE+ constantes.CELL_SIZE // 2,                                                i * constantes.CELL_SIZE + constantes.CELL_SIZE // 2))
       screen.blit(text, text_rect)



Tu condicional encargado de renderizar el texto está fuera del segundo ciclo for. Esto hace que ese if se ejecute solo una vez por cada iteración del primer for, justo después de terminar la ejecución del for anidado y tomando el último valor para j generado por este último (3 en tu caso).
El resultado en que solo dibuja el texto de la última columna de cada fila. El código debería ser:
def draw_screen():
    screen.fill(constantes.WHITE)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size=60)
    message_font = pygame.font.Font(None, size=30)

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            value = board[i][j]
            color = constantes.COLORS.get(value, constantes.COLORS[0])
            pygame.draw.rect(
                screen,
                color,
                rect=(
                    j * constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                    i * constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                    constantes.CELL_SIZE,
                    constantes.CELL_SIZE
                ),
                width=0
            )
            
            if value != 0:
                text = font.render(str(value), True, constantes.BLACK, None)
                text_rect = text.get_rect(
                    center = (
                        j * constantes.CELL_SIZE + constantes.CELL_SIZE // 2,
                        i * constantes.CELL_SIZE + constantes.CELL_SIZE // 2
                    )
                )
                screen.blit(text, text_rect)


MUCHAS Gracias amigo, me ayudaste. Ahora veo la importancia de una correcta identación.
